# How to Deserialize response JSON in List Object?

Tags: c#, json, httpresponse

I have a C# application, it send a http Request and received a response from WebServer.

This is the code and it found:

```
    String url = "http://myurl";
    var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";

    using (var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse())
    {
    log.Info(httpResponse);
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var objText = reader.ReadToEnd();
        ResponseJSON myojb = (ResponseJSON)js.Deserialize(objText, typeof(ResponseJSON));

    }

}
```

objText contains that response

```
"{"status":1,
    "message":"Ok",
    "people":[
        {
            "fiscalCode":"ASSISTITO2",
            "name":"Marco",
            "surname":"Puzzolante",
            "sex":"M",
            "bornDate":null,
            "cityCode":null
        },
        {"fiscalCode":"PLMLCU",
            "name":"Luca",
            "surname":"Palumbo",
            "sex":"M",
            "bornDate":"1983-04-22T00:00:00",
            "cityCode":"FO"
        }
    ]
}"
```

Now I have this Object "ResponseJSON". It have populate onlky two fields (status and message).
The ResponseJSON is:

```
public class ResponseJSON
{
   public int status { set; get; }
   public String message { set; get; }
   public List<Person> person { set;  get; }
}
```

This Object don't have populate a List of Person.

The object Person is:

```
public class Person
{
   public String fiscalCode { set; get; }
   public String name { set; get; }
   public String surname { set; get; }
   public String sex { set; get; }
   public String bornDate { set; get; }
   public String cityCode { set; get; }
   public String provinceCode { set; get; }
   public String username { set; get; }
   public String bloodGroup { set; get; }
}
```

Where is my error?

Can we help me?

Reguards

Comment: I have no error but the List<Person> person is no populate...

Answer (score 4):

Your `ResponseJSON` class does not match your JSON.

Change the `person` property to `people` to reflect the JSON.

```
public class ResponseJSON
{
   public int Status { set; get; }
   public String Message { set; get; }
   public List<Person> People { set;  get; }
}
```

[`JavaScriptSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) will deserialize case insensitive, so you can PascalCase your properties if your JSON is camelCase.

Also there is a generic overload of [`Deserialize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355316.aspx):

```
var myojb = js.Deserialize<ResponseJSON>(objText);
```